# I'm trying to add to mipmap in my app I have missing files/errors but it won't let me

Tags: android, layout, android-drawable, android-mipmap

I am trying to fix these errors which has caused the build to fail. But I am noticing in the newest version of Studio it wont let me add the image files to mipmap to fix the problem. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: Try to rebuild project .

Comment: Who knows? Research the error you are getting. Few are going to try and figure out what is going on from a screencap.

Answer (score 0):

Your project doesn't build because in your XML file there is a `ImageView` with unrecognized image/source,  `@mipmap/ic_default_user`. Thus, you must change the source image to one that the XML will recognize:

- Instead of `@mipmap/ic_default_user` write some thing else. e.g `@mipmap/ic_launcher` or `@mipmap/ic_launcher_round`
- You may see what images the XML recognize by writing `"@mipmap/"`  and then press `ctrl+space`  when you are in focus of `"@mipmap/"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <background android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
    <foreground android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground" />
```

just put this in your file and it will work